# Start the workflow by using user Account

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

Presently am using following c# code to start a workflow

```
 private static void StartWorkflow(SPListItem listItem)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(listItem.Web.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(listItem.Web.ID))
                    {
                        elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPWorkflowManager manager = elevatedSite.WorkflowManager;
                        SPListItem elevatedListItem = elevatedWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listItem.ParentList.Title).GetItemById(listItem.ID);
                        foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in manager.GetItemWorkflows(elevatedListItem))
                        {
                            SPWorkflowAssociation wfAssoc = elevatedListItem.ParentList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(workflow.ParentAssociation.Name, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                            elevatedListItem.Web.Site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(elevatedListItem, wfAssoc, wfAssoc.AssociationData, true);
                            elevatedListItem.Update();
                        }

                        // Get the workflow by name that's associated with the list item
                        elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

This will start the workflow using system account. Is there any way that, I can start the workflow using list items' created by column? I would like to start the workflow using perticular user account.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some RND I got the solution to the question. We need to pass the user token to the the web object. Here is my answer

```
  private void StartWorkflow(SPListItem item, string wfName, SPUserToken userToken)
        {
            using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(item.Web.Site.ID, userToken))
            {
                using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList parentList = elevatedWeb.Lists.TryGetList(item.ParentList.ToString());
                    SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationCollection = parentList.WorkflowAssociations;
                    foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection)
                    {
                        if (association.Name == wfName)
                        {
                            elevatedSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(item, association, association.AssociationData);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```